# How do I efficiently find the row indices of multiple elements in a 2D matrix?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, arraylist, indexing

say,

```
C = [ [1,2,3],[1,3,4],[3,5,6]]
item_list=[1,3,4]
```

I used the following code to accomplish what I wanted :

```
    rind = [[i for i in range(len(C)) if item in C[i]]
        for item in item_list]
```

I got the rind to be 
[[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1]]

I actually want my o/p to be as a 1d array like [0 1 0 1 2 1]

Could you either suggest a completely alternative approach to obtain row indices or advise me on how  to convert the list of arrays to a 1D array ?

Please note that the actual size of C is 2 M * 4 and item_list is 20000.

Answer (score 1):

You want to [flatten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) the list.  For instance:

```
a = [[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [1]]
flat_list = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]


In [5]: flat_list
```

> Out[5]: [0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1]

In the case of your particular code, you could do:

```
rind = [[i for i in range(len(C)) if item in C[i]]
        for item in item_list]
rind = [item for sublist in rind for item in sublist]
```

Alternatively, you could do it in one line like this:

```
rind = list(map(set, [[i for i in range(len(C)) if item in C[i]]
        for item in item_list]))
```

Comment: I recommend using `a_set = list(map(set, a))` in your list comprehension. The one-off conversion cost is likely less than the benefit of O(1) lookup in loops.

Comment: Good idea.  I'll write the map and edit accordingly.

Comment: (Just realized you cleverly use `set` for flattening here, so no actual map has to be written.  Cool trick!)